# InstallShield 2012: Cryptic error code IISRT: -1204

Tags: installshield

Try to finish up an install script that I haven't touched in about 3 weeks.  Install was working last time I tried but now getting error.  It seems to have something to do with ISIISCosting but Google has been no help.

```
MSI (s) (D0:54) [11:09:53:273]: Doing action: ISIISCosting
Action start 11:09:53: ISIISCosting.
MSI (s) (D0:F8) [11:09:53:341]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer  \MSI30AF.tmp, Entrypoint: ISIISCosting
MSI (s) (D0!14) [11:09:53:403]: Note: 1: 2711 2:  
InstallShield 11:09:53: Error with IISRT: -1204
CustomAction ISIISCosting returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 11:09:53: ISIISCosting. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:09:53: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

I restarted the IIS server and I know it is working as prior to this error we query the IIS server for a list of Web Sites and display them in a panel.

Found out that -1204 = ERROR_IISRT_INVALID_VROOTCOMPNAME

IIS issue or InstallShield issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any InstallScript involved here, just how you define the website and InstallShield's built in custom actions  ( cost, rollback, install, commit, uninstall type stuff ) going through that data and passing it onto IIS.

My guess would be that the data is using special characters or something that isn't allowed.  It's hard to say without seeing the data.  The log doesn't tell enough.

Comment: So there were several web applications defined for this install.  I had removed the components associated with one of them and they were temporary and I was going to configure the new ones.  When I deleted them the entry in the Internet Information Services / Web Sites component field for that web app was also deleted.  It appears that the ISIISCosting action runs for all web apps even if their "Feature" is not selected for install.  By setting the "Component" value I am able to run successfully again.  The key was "MSI (s) (D0!14) [11:09:53:403]: Note: 1: 2711 2: " in the log.

Comment: what I've seen before is certain IS IIS tables have joins to the component table.  Sometimes when you delete the components it doesn't cascade the delete down to the IIS tables.  This is probably your problem as the tables can't find the components they are associated to and can't decide whether they need to install or not ( costing process ).

Comment: So I've removed some components from an install and am now having this issue.  Is the only way to fix it to remove the Web Site from the ISM's IIS and then add it back?  Or is there something more elegant?

Comment: Nevermind...the issue was I removed a component and didn't remove the IIS app pool and web site associated with the component (Component field was empty for both).  Hope my stupid mistake helps someone.